# SVN ignore on repo export

Tags: svn

We have some files (bash scripts) that we put on the project repo, but we want them to be ignored when we export the repo to deploy them.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're trying to make svn do something that would more properly be done using a build automation system. Depending on your environment and goals, Make, Ant, NAnt or somesuch might be appropriate. In simpler cases, a shell script will do just as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible.

You will have to write a script which exports the project and then deletes whatever needs to be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can delete them after you export.